# Can you fix scratches in Little Tykes furniture?

Tags: sanding, plastic

Little Tykes has thick plastic furniture and toys.  Is there a way to make them look new?  Buff, fill, what?

Answer (score 1):

Buffing followed by acid etch (to restore texture).  Overall a pretty rough job.  You'll want to check the plastic type (found next to a 'recycling' symbol usually) for additional guidance.  LDPE is common.  Some people use heat guns, but for maximum potential entertainment value why not try a blowtorch?  LDPE is actually pretty hard to set on fire.

Comment: What would you use to buff it.  Give me a couple steps.  I can try it out on the back of something to see if it works.

Comment: A Dico Plastic Buffing Wheel BP40-4 would probably do it. Try a heat gun to get stuff soft and a cotton buffing wheel like the BP40.  You'll have to experiment to get the right mix of abrasion and effectiveness.  Once you get the rough edges off the scratches they may just well look "good enough".